# Newbie VSCode find/replace adding a new line at the begining of the replaced text, Any fix?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, tslint

Recently I found a very annoying thing that when I find/replace text in TSScript file, the VSCode adds a new line in front of the replaced text, I double check there are no new lines in the find or replace text.
Appreciate any help.

I am using VSCode 1.40.1 in MacOS Mojave. I do not have anyother issue except I cannot use the find/replace because of this.

Comment: Can you share the search and replacement text? Also are you in regexp search mode?

Comment: Thank you. No I am not using regex. Somehow this got fixed itself when I try this morning. What I was trying then was to normalize a mock json data file { city: 'place' } into something line 'const city='place'; And it was keep adding const city = in first line and pushing the 'place' to next line. Sorry I have no real code anymore. It is not adding the new line anymore.